# Отправка сообщения telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу бота телеграмм и мне необходимо в новой функции отправить сообщение пользователю в новой функции. Логика такая: пользователю генерируется пример и просят ввести ответ. После ввода ответа он проверяется в новой функции и отправляет результат проверки (правильно или неправильно). После этого юзера возвращает в предыдущую функцию. И в ней хотелось бы сразу отправлять новый сгенерированный пример без этой надоедливой кнопки "продолжить". Возможно ли это сделать?
Ниже приведен пример, как работает это сейчас (с кнопкой "продолжить")

```
def sum1_hard(message):
     if message.text.lower() == 'продолжить':
        from math_bot import sum_hard
        global a, b, result, x, y, z
        a, b, result, x, y, z = sum_hard(a, b, result, x, y, z)
        send_message = str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + '?'
        message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=keyboards_bot.math_buttons(result, x, y, z))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum_hard_check)
def sum_hard_check(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'выход':
        send_message = 'Вы вышли из режима тренировки'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    elif message.text.lower() == str(result):
        send_message = 'Верно!'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message)
        send_message = 'Для продолжения нажмите кнопку'
        message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=keyboards_bot.continue1())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum1_hard)
    else:
        send_message = 'Неправльный ответ!'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message)
        send_message = 'Для продолжения нажмите кнопку'
        message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=keyboards_bot.continue1())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum1_hard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему объединением этих 2-х блоков и зацикливанием этой функции:

```py
def sum1(message):
    global a, b, result, x, y, z
    if message.text == 'Выход':
        logger(message)
        send_message = 'Вы вышли из режима тренировки'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    else:
        if message.text == str(result):
            send_message = 'Верно!'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message)
            write(message.from_user.id, 1)
        else:
            send_message = 'Неправльный ответ!'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message)
            write(message.from_user.id, 2)
        from math_bot import sum
        a, b, result, x, y, z = sum(a, b, result, x, y, z)
        send_message = str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + '?'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_message, reply_markup=keyboards_bot.math_buttons(result, x, y, z))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду ты используешь pyTelegramBotAPI (telebot). В этой библиотеки есть `bot.register_next_step_handler`, ознакомься с его функционалом. Если я правильно понял, то он решит твою проблему.

Comment: Да, Я пользуюсь `register_next_setp_handler`, но дело в том, что при переходе в новую функцию бот не отправляет сообщение. Ему необходимо сообщение от пользователя, чтобы отправить его.

Comment: Ты слышал про рекурсивные функции? Тебе надо сделать рекурсию. Сейчас у тебя логически странно выглядит код. Два условия которые делают одно и тоже, в любом случае ты попадаешь в рекурсию, только через `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum1_hard)`. Попробуй заменить эту строку на  `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sum_hard_check)`, и тогда будет вызвана та же функция что и сейчас исполнялась без выхода в `sum1_hard`